# Проверка адаптивности сайта на Safari

Tags: html, safari

Всем привет. Есть сайт, адаптировал с помощью bootstrap. Вроде все ок, и тут открывают его на safari и о боже, все криво косо. Как можно проверить адаптивность сайта на safari не имея macbook

Comment: Я бы предложил поставить виртуальную машину с макосью, и там будет нормальный сафари

Answer (score 3):

https://www.browserstack.com лучшая тулза чтоб тестировать кроссбраузерность та кроссплатформенность. Можешь использовать ее вместе с https://temp-mail.org/ru/ чтобы не создавать новые мейлы и использовать trial период.

Answer (score 0):

Можно проверить на https://www.browserstack.com/start. 30 минут для новичков или 29 баксов в месяц безлимита на одного.